# Add Variable to $_SERVER array via php.ini

Tags: php

I need to add a variable to the $_SERVER array in a php script. Is there a possibility to do this via the php.ini file? I want to add the variable for all scripts on the webserver, so it's quite inconvenient to add it in each script.

Thanks,
TSS

Comment: you may add it in one script and then include it in all other

Comment: This would be the fallback solution, but it would make the whole workflow a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Apache, try the SetEnv module.

(you can see more here: [Declaring global variable with php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052558/declaring-global-variable-with-php-ini))

Comment: The problem is, I really need to set it in the $_SERVER array

Comment: But the solution with auto_prepend_file mentioned in the post could work, I will have a try.

Answer (score 9):

You can set it in your .htaccess or in the apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    SetEnv PARAM "VALUE"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

It will be added to the variable `$_SERVER['PARAM'].`

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way to add things to $_SERVER via php.ini (which doesn't mean there's no way to do it).

However, you could add things to $_ENV, server-wide, using [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#page-header) in httpd.conf (assuming apache, here).  There are likely methods for doing this with other web servers, but I'm not sure what they are.

Comment: The problem is, I really need to set it in the $_SERVER array

Comment: One of the good/bad things about php is that superglobals (like $_SERVER) are writable. Meaning, you can add new keys to the superglobal by just calling `$_SERVER['your_key'] = 'hello world';`

Comment: @AlanChavez - you're right, but OP was specifically asking about setting a variable globally across the server.