# Where to change $_SERVER variable in apache 2 on server side?

Tags: php, debian, apache2

I am using apache 2 on Debian server.

Where I can find list of all **$_SERVER** variables?

For example, to change **$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']** or **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']**?

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155150/where-in-apache-2-do-you-set-the-servername-directive-globally would be useful

Comment: How about. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php?

Comment: List of all $_SERVER vars is here [Php $_SERVER var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). But all of them come from different places.
Considering your question - look up [Apache 2 manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Variable to $\_SERVER array via php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676274/add-variable-to-server-array-via-php-ini)