# Where to keep the globals variables in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, global

I am used to use Java and Spring Framework. But not so long ago I started learning PHP , to get familiar with another kind of language.

I am trying to write a simple thing for drawing using html canvas, so more then 1 user can use that at the same time to draw.

In Java i would use a class variable in controller to store the picture draw by users. And every 1-2 seconds users send the request with the new data they have drawn, so i can add the changes to the global variable. and then send the changes to every user. When a new user enters, the server sends the whole picture to him.

So, my question is, how can i store an application global variable in PHP? like in this example with picture...
As i see, after finishing, the PHP halts and all the variables die with it, right? So is there any way to make a variable application global? So i can get access to it from different parts of application?

I can save it to text file before finishing the script. and every time new request happens, read it again from text file, make changes and then write back to text file... but it's so crazy... isn't there any way just like in Spring Framework and Java that i used before?

Comment: In a database, filesystem file or cache like memcache or redis

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring global variable with php.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052558/declaring-global-variable-with-php-ini)

Answer (score 1):

You need a form of persistent storage. By persistent, I mean storage that is not based on an individual user's session like the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array is. [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) are useful for storage for a single user, but one user cannot access the session data of another user.

Persistent storage can be achieved a few ways. Some options: checking a row in a database table or storing a value in a file like you mentioned.

**Database storage**

Check out php's [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for more information on doing this via a database. This will require knowledge of MySQL syntax.

**File storage**

Check out php's [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for examples on how to easily interact with retrieving data from files and setting data in files.

Answer (score -1):

As DevZer0 answered - you want to use sessions. More information about session you will find in the php manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php