# how to configure debug mode for production environment in Cake 3.2?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

The latest Cake will produce this inside the `app.php`

`'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),`

I need to set up for production use.

How do I make it debug false on production server without changing this?

Answer (score 2):

**Apache**

You can set the Environment `DEBUG` value to false via the `.htaccess` on the production server.
You'll just have to add `SetEnv DEBUG false` to the `.htaccess` file you're using.

[This StackOverflow post explains it a little more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052651/1604068)

**Nginx**

If you are using Nginx you can set environment values in [two different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19491780/1604068).

You can add an extra `fastcgi_param` to the locationblock with the desired name and value:

```
location / {
    ...
    fastcgi_param DEBUG false; 
    ...
}
```

**php-fpm**

You also can configure the php-fpm or the php-cgi config and add the following:

```
env[DEBUG] = false
```

[According to CakePHP's documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/function-env.html) the `env()` requires one parameter, they environment value key. The second parameter is optional and a default, in case the value isn't set.

Comment: Unfortunately no but I will edit the answer and add the nginx side of things :)

Comment: Sorry I tried the nginx one but it didn't work. As for the php-fpm, the file to change is which one ? I have a `/etc/php/fpm/` folder.

Comment: have you restarted `php-fpm` afterwards?