# Using .env file in production - conflicting information

Tags: security, environment-variables

I am developing in CakePHP and it uses a `.env` file in `config` - below is a snippet.
It specifically says "having this file in production is considered a security risk."

I understand about not committing an `.env` to git/version control, so as not to expose secrets to the public; and I also understand about not including secret keys directly in source code; but I don't understand how we can then use `.env` variables but it's a security risk to include in production? It seems counterintuitive.

I have scanned a bunch of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76220034/env-file-in-production-using-pure-php) questions and [articles](https://dev.to/wiseai/continue-using-env-files-as-usual-2am5) [and](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/should-we-use-the-env-file-in-production-as-well-and-how-to-protect-it) I still don't understand what the correct best practice is?

Some sources say ensure the file is outside of `public_html` and not accessible - fine - others say you should set the EVs on the host?

Edit - there's also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738233/how-to-configure-debug-mode-for-production-environment-in-cake-3-2) to set it using `SetEnv` in apache `.htaccess` - but how is this any better than using a `.env` file? if both are out of the document root.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Used as a default to seed config/.env which
# enables you to use environment variables to configure
# the aspects of your application that vary by
# environment.
#
# Having this file in production is considered a **SECURITY RISK** and also decreases
# the boostrap performance of your application.
#
# To use this file, first copy it into `config/.env`. Also ensure the related
# code block for loading this file is uncommented in `config/boostrap.php`
#
# In development .env files are parsed by PHP
# and set into the environment. This provides a simpler
# development workflow over standard environment variables.
export APP_NAME="__APP_NAME__"
export DEBUG="true"
export APP_ENCODING="UTF-8"
export APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE="en_US"
export APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE="UTC"
export SECURITY_SALT="__SALT__"
```